# Build WHERE insert_fields failed

Tags: mysql, vb6

At the moment I am getting an error "Build WHERE -> insert_fields()". This error is occurring on this code:

```
Do Until rCurrent.EOF 
    rCurrent.MoveNext
Loop
```

rCurrent is an ADODBRecordSet that has been given the following value:

```vb
sSQL = ""
sSQL = sSQL & "SELECT v_final_transactions.* " & vbCrLf
sSQL = sSQL & "FROM   v_final_transactions " & vbCrLf
sSQL = sSQL & "WHERE  ( " & vbCrLf
sSQL = sSQL & "       ( " & vbCrLf
sSQL = sSQL & "( v_final_transactions.contact_id ) = " & rcampaigninclusion!contact_id & " ) " & vbCrLf
sSQL = sSQL & "AND " & vbCrLf
sSQL = sSQL & "( " & vbCrLf
sSQL = sSQL & "( v_final_transactions.dbd_segment ) = '" & rCampaignInclusion!PRODUCT_SEGMENT_1 & "' ) ) " & vbCrLf
sSQL = sSQL & " OR ( " & vbCrLf
sSQL = sSQL & "( ( v_final_transactions.contact_id ) = " & rcampaigninclusion!contact_id & " ) " & vbCrLf
sSQL = sSQL & "AND " & vbCrLf
sSQL = sSQL & "( " & vbCrLf
sSQL = sSQL & "( v_final_transactions.dbd_segment ) = '" & rCampaignInclusion!PRODUCT_SEGMENT_2 & "' ) ) " & vbCrLf
sSQL = sSQL & " OR " & vbCrLf
sSQL = sSQL & "(( ( v_final_transactions.contact_id ) = " & rcampaigninclusion!contact_id & " ))"        
Set rCurrent = New ADODB.Recordset
rCurrent.Open sSQL, cDS, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
```

The final SQL comes out as:

```sql
SELECT V_FINAL_TRANSACTIONS.* 
FROM V_FINAL_TRANSACTIONS 
WHERE ( 
      ( 
( V_FINAL_TRANSACTIONS.CONTACT_ID ) = 1036219 ) 
AND 
( 
( V_FINAL_TRANSACTIONS.DBD_SEGMENT ) ='Acrobat' ) ) 
 OR ( 
( ( V_FINAL_TRANSACTIONS.CONTACT_ID ) = 1036219 ) 
AND 
( 
( V_FINAL_TRANSACTIONS.DBD_SEGMENT ) = '' ) ) 
 OR 
(( ( V_FINAL_TRANSACTIONS.CONTACT_ID ) = 1036219 ))
```

Here is the logic that runs:

```vb
If rCurrent.Properties.Count > 0 Then

    If (rCurrent.EOF = False) Then
        rCurrent.MoveFirst

    End If

    Do Until rCurrent.EOF
        dTransDate = rCurrent!TRANSACTION_DATE

        If (rCampaignInclusion!CAMPAIGN_ID = 446) And (dTransDate >= rCampaignInclusion!DATE_UPDATE) And (dTransDate <= (rCampaignInclusion!DATE_UPDATE + 90)) Then

            iDifference = dTransDate - rCampaignInclusion!DATE_UPDATE
            iCampaignHistory = rCampaignInclusion!CAMPAIGN_HISTORY_ID

            If rCurrent!REVENUE > 0 Then
                iTransactionRevenue = rCurrent!REVENUE
            Else
                iTransactionRevenue = 0
            End If


            sSQLMatched = "INSERT INTO TMP_MATCH_CON_HISTORY_UPDATE ( TRANSACTION_08_ID, CAMPAIGN_HISTORY_ID, DATE_UPDATE, RESULT_VALUE_2, NO_DAYS) SELECT " & rCurrent!TRANSACTION_08_ID & ", " & iCampaignHistory & ", '" & Year(Date) & "-" & Month(Date) & "-" & Day(Date) & "', " & iTransactionRevenue & ", " & iDifference & ";"
            cDS.Execute (sSQLMatched)

            'rCurrent.Edit
            'rCurrent!MATCHED = "Y"
            'rCurrent.Update

            sSQLMatched = "UPDATE TMP_MATCH_TRANSACTIONS SET MATCHED='Y' WHERE TMP_MATCH_TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_08_ID=" & rCurrent!TRANSACTION_08_ID
            cDS.Execute (sSQLMatched)


        ElseIf (dTransDate >= rCampaignInclusion!CAMPAIGN_DATE_START) And (dTransDate <= rCampaignInclusion!CAMPAIGN_DATE_END) Then
            iDifference = dTransDate - rCampaignInclusion!CAMPAIGN_DATE_START
            iCampaignHistory = rCampaignInclusion!CAMPAIGN_HISTORY_ID


            If rCurrent!REVENUE > 0 Then
                iTransactionRevenue = rCurrent!REVENUE
            Else
                iTransactionRevenue = 0
            End If

            sSQLMatched = "INSERT INTO TMP_MATCH_CON_HISTORY_UPDATE ( TRANSACTION_08_ID, CAMPAIGN_HISTORY_ID, DATE_UPDATE, RESULT_VALUE_2, NO_DAYS) SELECT " & rCurrent!TRANSACTION_08_ID & ", " & iCampaignHistory & ", '" & Year(Date) & "-" & Month(Date) & "-" & Day(Date) & "', " & iTransactionRevenue & ", " & iDifference & ";"
            cDS.Execute (sSQLMatched)


            'rCurrent!MATCHED = "Y"
            'rCurrent.Update

            sSQLMatched = "UPDATE TMP_MATCH_TRANSACTIONS SET MATCHED='Y' WHERE TMP_MATCH_TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_08_ID=" & rCurrent!TRANSACTION_08_ID
            cDS.Execute (sSQLMatched)


        End If

        rCurrent.MoveNext

    Loop
```

So my question is what is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: How about posting some more of your code?

Comment: I've added some more, however there is not any more that is particularly relevant

Comment: Before opening your recordset, do a `debug.print sSQL` and look for any anomalies. I suspect one or more of your rcampaigninclusion fields isn't giving you the data you're expecting.

Comment: @TomCollins Ive added some more code now to show the logic, you will note that rCurrent.MoveNext is right at the end. The other parts run fine....could the issue be because rCurrent is a view and not a table?

Comment: Does the routine manage to process more than one loop iteration before failure?  You can find out by following Tom's suggestion.  Personally I find it makes the code a lot more readable if you use line continuation characters `_` when building your SQL strings rather than concatenating onto a variable each line (just my preference).

Comment: Debug.Print came out with this SELECT V_FINAL_TRANSACTIONS.* FROM V_FINAL_TRANSACTIONS WHERE (((V_FINAL_TRANSACTIONS.CONTACT_ID)=1036219) AND ((V_FINAL_TRANSACTIONS.DBD_SEGMENT)='Acrobat')) OR (((V_FINAL_TRANSACTIONS.CONTACT_ID)=1036219) AND ((V_FINAL_TRANSACTIONS.DBD_SEGMENT)='')) OR (((V_FINAL_TRANSACTIONS.CONTACT_ID)=1036219));

Comment: Have you tried dropping that straight into MySQL to see if you get the expected results?

Comment: I know that this code works in VBA since it has been performed there, I have been tasked with porting across the code to VB6, I believe the issue has something to do with the records being locked for editing, as I had an issue with this in an earlier section of the code

Comment: @MatthewPigram That SQL you pasted did not come from the code you pasted (upper case fields, lack of `;`, etc). Can you provide the current code or SQL output. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to give the full error message (including any error numbers) to help diagnose the issue.

Whilst we are waiting for that, I've simplified your SQL a bit:

```
SELECT v_final_transactions.* 
FROM   v_final_transactions 
WHERE
( 
    ( 
        ( v_final_transactions.contact_id ) = [rcampaigninclusion!contact_id]
    ) 
    AND 
    ( 
        ( v_final_transactions.dbd_segment ) = '[rCampaignInclusion!PRODUCT_SEGMENT_1]'
    )
) 
OR
( 
    (
        ( v_final_transactions.contact_id ) = [rcampaigninclusion!contact_id]
    )
    AND 
    ( 
        ( v_final_transactions.dbd_segment ) = '[rCampaignInclusion!PRODUCT_SEGMENT_2]'
    )
) 
OR 
(
    (
        ( v_final_transactions.contact_id ) = [rcampaigninclusion!contact_id]
    )
)
```

Looking at this, it seems that the first two chunks of the top level WHERE statement are redundant. Even if

```
( v_final_transactions.dbd_segment ) = '[rCampaignInclusion!PRODUCT_SEGMENT_1]'
```

or

```
( v_final_transactions.dbd_segment ) = '[rCampaignInclusion!PRODUCT_SEGMENT_2]'
```

evaluate as false, the entire where clause evaluates to simply:

```
( v_final_transactions.contact_id ) = [rcampaigninclusion!contact_id]
```

And by the way, surely you don't need to surround every fieldname in the WHERE clause with parentheses? It makes it a lot easier if you leave them out.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not write this code, I am just porting it to VB6 from VBA. However you did pick up on a logic error where at the end of the code I had for some reason added a redundant line (the last OR clause)